# Is it possible to use mongoose to update a document with math expression?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is mainly to solve competition problem (for example multiple threads trying to change a single document).

Typically if I want to update a document's attribute I would need to use `fine` and first read the current output of the document, do some math, and then `update` the document.

This is a little troubling when I have multiple threads trying to change a single document, I'd have to place a service to queue the mutations which in itself is arguably inefficient.

Is it possible to update a document with math expression such as:

`db.album.updateOne({albumid},{view: $view + 1},{upsert:true});`

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you are trying to do the operator you are looking for is the [`$inc` field update operator](http://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#up._S_inc):

> The $inc operator accepts positive and negative values.
>   If the field does not exist, $inc creates the field and sets the field
>   to the specified value.
>   Use of the $inc operator on a field with a null value will generate an
>   error.
>   $inc is an atomic operation within a single document.

```
db.products.update(
   { sku: "abc123" },
   { $inc: { quantity: -2 } }  // substract 2 from quantity
)
```

Comment: Thx, `$inc creates the field and sets the field to the specified value` what does this mean? Does it create 0 or should I set the default value, if so, how?

Comment: You should have a default value for numeric fields.